# Javascript array conversion to jQuery.post's data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I am trying to send different values to php script using jQuery.post

The data I want to send are links like this

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg
http://example.com/image2.jpg
http://example.com/image3.jpg
http://example.com/image4.jpg
```

I don't have an exact amount of these links they would vary depending on the user interacting with my script

I am storing these links in a javascript array "fileLinks".

what I want to do is to send these links to php using jQuery.post

Can I format these links in this shape?

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            { action : 'ajax-rform',
              link1: http://example.com/image1.jpg,
              link2: http://example.com/image2.jpg,
              link3: http://example.com/image3.jpg,
              link4: http://example.com/image4.jpg,
            },
            function(data){
                jQuery("#fileupload").after('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your registration has been recieved.</p>');
            }
           );
```

In php I just need to use for loop and replace the link1 and http://example.com/image1.jpg with the arrays and php would iterate it for me but what should I do in javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the array. jQuery will encode it with array notation, and PHP will decide it back into an array:

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            { action : 'ajax-rform',
              link: fileLinks
            },
            function(data){
                jQuery("#fileupload").after('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your registration has been recieved.</p>');
            });
```

In PHP, you can access the array as `$_POST['link']`.

Comment: When I use this, it sends fileLinks values in simultaneous connections and because of that php script runs more than one time I want PHP to be executed only once. Is there any to do it?

Comment: If that's happening, it's for some other reason. This code won't cause multiple connections.

Comment: Thanks Barmer - yes you were right I was using .each method and it was causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a json array and then use php's `json_decode` method?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just make a data object to send, populate it from your array like this

```
var postData = { action : 'ajax-rform' };
for(var i = 0; i < fileLinks.length; i++){
 postData["link"+(i+1)] = fileLinks[i];
}
```

And then use that in your ajax

```
jQuery.post(MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    postData,
    function(data){
        jQuery("#fileupload").after('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your registration has been recieved.</p>');
    }
 );
```